# Get Raw json from GraphQL Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql

I want to get raw json data from GraphQL flutter.

here is part of the data I want to get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "countries": [
      {
        "name": "Andorra",
        "code": "AD",
        "native": "Andorra",
        "phone": "376"
      },
      {
        "name": "United Arab Emirates",
        "code": "AE",
        "native": "دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة",
        "phone": "971"
      },
```

but this is the result that GraphQL returns to me:

```
{__typename: Query,
 countries: [{__typename: Country, name: Andorra, code: AD, native: Andorra, phone: 376}, 
{__typename: Country, name: United Arab Emirates,
 code: AE, native: دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة, phone: 971},
```

the format is all wrong...

and this is my code:

```
  void getCountryName() async {
    pageState(AppState.loading);

    String q = """
{
  countries {
    name
    code
    native
    phone
  }
}
""";
    QueryResult res = await countriesClient.query(
      QueryOptions(
        document: gql(q),
        optimisticResult: Country,
        fetchPolicy: FetchPolicy.networkOnly,
      ),
    );

  }

print(res.data);
```

Comment: Looks like your GraphQL is sending also typenames in __typename, which you can/should ignore. Other than that, you have all the data you need. IS there a reason why you want it in a specific format - why you can't handle extra __typename property?

Comment: @Andrija I'm want to parse the data with a model given from backend. I can't do it with this data since it does not match with the server data.

Comment: How do you parse it? I'm still not clear on where the problem is - the structure you get is the same pretty much.

Comment: you got any solution?